# In TortoiseSVN, why can't I show the log older than 6 weeks or so?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

If I right click on my working folder, and choose TortoiseSVN->Show Log it shows a very useful log of changes that have been made to the repository. However it only shows the last 6 weeks or so. If I try to change the date range it won't let me - clicking on the dates in the calender does nothing and if I edit the date textbox it just changes it back.

Answer (score 87):

Ah I worked it out - you have to use the button down the bottom of the log dialog window that says "Show Range" or maybe "Show All". If you click the arrow next to the button you can then specify a date range.

The date filters at the top of the dialog box seem to only filter whatever you are currently looking at.

Refer to the screenshot below,

[image]

Comment: also tried it but didn't work for me as well. EDIT: It's working now. It didn't work on show all but it worked when I chose the show range and specified the dates I want to show.

Comment: Thanks for finding this!  Why they hid that button way down at the bottom of the page is beyond me.  You'd think it would be by the From and To controls...